# Flutter run Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal, sdk

I am trying to run my flutter project on VS code,

flutter doctor not showing the issues.

```
    C:\Users\isurus>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (2 weeks ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\isurus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\isurus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.22.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.56

No issues found!
```

When I run the flutter run or any command on vscode terminal shows the bellow error.

PS C:\Projects\test_mvvm> flutter run
Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1

- flutter run
- 

At line:1 char:1

- flutter run
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUaY1.png
  ```

Comment: follow this thread : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65378

Comment: The issue is regarding the vscode terminal. can anyone please help to resolve this?